# Subtract X Percent from Value in Java

Tags: java, recursion, counter, subtraction

I have a loop counter and depending on the value of the counter
I'd like to subtract 7% from 10 equal to the value of the counter. For example, if the value of the counter is 1 then I subtract 7% from 10 once. If the value of the counter is two I subtract 7% from 10 which gives me 9.3 and then subtract 7% from 9.3. And so on.

I am using the following code:

```
double ten = 10.0;
double seven = 0.70;
double score = ten * seven / 100.0;
```

When this runs I can easily subtract 7% from ten. However, how can I change it so that the next time it runs it will subtract 7% from 9.3, not 10?

Comment: If you want to subtract 7%, you need to multiply by `.93`

Answer (score 2):

Just use

```
double factor=Math.pow(0.93, counter);
double outputValue = inputValue * factor;
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like,

```
double ten = 10.0;
int seven = 7;
double score = ten;
while (Math.round(score) > 0) {
    double startScore = score;
    score = startScore - ((((double) seven) / 100) * startScore);
    System.out.printf("%f - %d%% = %f%n", startScore, seven, score);
}
```

Output is

```
10.000000 - 7% = 9.300000
9.300000 - 7% = 8.649000
8.649000 - 7% = 8.043570
8.043570 - 7% = 7.480520
7.480520 - 7% = 6.956884
6.956884 - 7% = 6.469902
6.469902 - 7% = 6.017009
6.017009 - 7% = 5.595818
5.595818 - 7% = 5.204111
5.204111 - 7% = 4.839823
4.839823 - 7% = 4.501035
4.501035 - 7% = 4.185963
4.185963 - 7% = 3.892946
3.892946 - 7% = 3.620439
3.620439 - 7% = 3.367009
3.367009 - 7% = 3.131318
3.131318 - 7% = 2.912126
2.912126 - 7% = 2.708277
2.708277 - 7% = 2.518698
2.518698 - 7% = 2.342389
2.342389 - 7% = 2.178422
2.178422 - 7% = 2.025932
2.025932 - 7% = 1.884117
....
0.510271 - 7% = 0.474552
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double score = 10.0;
score = score * .93;
```

Comment: You should read the question more carefully or provide explanation how does it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `0.70` is not `7%` but `70%`

If you want to do it recursively

you can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println(subs(10,2));
} 

public static double subs(double result, int counter) {
    if (counter == 0)
        return result;
    else
        return subs(result - (result * 0.07), --counter);
}
```

**result:**

```
8.649000000000001
```

Above code is using recursion that will calculate it until the counter reach its 0 value to terminate the recursion and return the result.